# Putting a longer javascript into executeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

Wanting to get the position/coordinates of an element and then trigger the click via the position/coordinates. Im planning to do it in javascript via the executeScript but realised it a bit long. Is there a better way to do some concatenation rather than my one liner. Reason im using javascript is because im more familiar in that then the selenium/nodejs way

```
driver.executeScript("var elem = document.querySelector('.mob-menu-icon');var leftPosition = elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;var topPosition = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;document.elementFromPoint(leftPosition, topPosition).click();");
```

Comment: Yes, you can supply a string with line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`driver.executeScript()` accept String or Function, so you can pass a function:

```
driver.executeScript(function(){
  var elem = document.querySelector('.mob-menu-icon');
  var leftPosition = elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var topPosition = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  document.elementFromPoint(leftPosition, topPosition).click();
});
```